# Code stops when trying to save Parse.com object information to NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

so I am making an app that searches for friends locations saved on parse.com. Before I begin, here is the method in question.

```
- (void)saveFriendLocationInfo {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Locations"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query whereKey:@"userString" equalTo:currentFriend];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *parseCurrentFriend, NSError *error) {
        if (!parseCurrentFriend) {
            NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh..."
                                                            message:@"Looks like that user doesnt exist. Might want to double check that."
                                                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [alertView show];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"ObjectID = %@", parseCurrentFriend.objectId);
            parseCurrentFriend[@"title"] = friendTitle;
            NSLog(@"Saved Title");
            parseCurrentFriend[@"description"] = friendDescription;
            NSLog(@"Saved Description");
            parseCurrentFriend[@"latitude"] = friendLatitude;
            NSLog(@"Saved Latitude");
            parseCurrentFriend[@"longitude"] = friendLongitude;
            NSLog(@"Saved Longitude");
        }
    }];
}
```

So this code all works fine at retrieving the required object. It reaches the NSLog line in the "else" statement where it is supposed to display the object ID. This displays the correct object id for the object that I am trying to receive. Now heres the weird part. The code seems to stop there. Nothing happens when trying to save the properties (title, description, lat, long) to the respective NSStrings; none of those other NSLog's below that are executed. But the weird thing is that there are no errors and the app keeps running as if that code below the first NSLog wasn't even there. Any insight into why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is that you never save the object. After you modify all of the values, you need to save the PFObject.

```
[parseCurrentFriend saveInBackground];
```

Edit: Since you are trying to extract the values, then you'd need to do it like below.

```
friendTitle       = parseCurrentFriend[@"title"];
friendDescription = parseCurrentFriend[@"description"];
friendLatitude    = parseCurrentFriend[@"latitude"];
friendLongitude   = parseCurrentFriend[@"longitude"];
```

Comment: Well I don't think that is necessary as I am only retrieving the data from parse, I am not trying to update any information with this specific method.

Comment: Then why are you assigning values to it?

Comment: I am trying to save the values from parse to the variable entitled friend..., is this the incorrect way to do so?

Comment: You have it backwards then.

Comment: so i should do variable = parse expression instead of parse expression = variable?

Comment: Wow that works perfectly, such a simple fix! I didn't realize that it was that sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, in programming, the object on the left is assigned the value on the right. Glad to help!